# Is it possible to have automatically generated destructors in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to have automatically generated destructors in C++?

It is too big burden to do it by ourselves all the time. Is it so hard
for the compiler to generate destructors? Can't it detect what is a "resource"
and release it in the destructor?

Comment: If you want to manage the resource, it's up to you. Most of the time you don't need to if you use the proper facilities of C++, and the default destructor is enough. But, imagine you wrapped the C function `fopen()` in a C++ class, and it should be closed in the destructore. How could the C++ compiler know it should call `fclose()` in the destructor ?

Comment: too big a burden? Sounds like you should be using RAII!

Comment: Arguably, quite a lot of destructors are automatically generated. Could you elaborate on what you are asking about? Maybe you can add an example of code that you think could be automatically made simpler by automatically generated destructors?

Comment: If your little objects clean themselves up, many of your big objects don't need custom destructors at all.

Comment: You are not entirely wrong. Having to release resources does indeed put a burden on a class. One might argue that this burden is so heavy that a class that takes it should not do anything else. Take a look at the [Rule of Zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html) for details.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Certainly it is, and that's exactly what the language does. If you don't declare a destructor, then one will be generated for you: it will invoke the destructor of each member and base subobject.

You only need to write your own destructor if you're managing a resource that isn't released automatically; for example, a raw pointer to something that you allocated with `new`. You shouldn't need such a thing in most classes - use containers, smart pointers and other RAII types to manage these automatically for you.

Comment: If you define a destructor, the compiler will still invoke the destructor of each member and base subobject.

Comment: You also need to write a destructor if it is to be virtual, i.e. for base classes.

Comment: @squelart No longer true in C++11. You can write `virtual ~Foo() = default;`.

Comment: @ruds One could argue that writing `= default` is writing a destructor! :-) But good point anyway, C++11 makes the intent clearer than writing `{}`.

Answer (score 10):

It can't be detected accurately. Even if the compiler observes that you allocate a resource in the constructor or in some other function of the object, it doesn't necessarily follow that it should be released in the destructor. It all depends whether or not the object "owns" the resource.

Fortunately, C++ does provide a means for you to inform the compiler explicitly what resources the object owns. This means is called "smart pointers", and the types you should read about are `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`. You can avoid writing destructors by thorough use of smart pointers. The compiler generates a destructor that destroys all your data members, so if the data members are smart pointers then the resources they control are destroyed at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it so hard for the compiler to generate destructors?

It is not a question of what is easy or hard for the compiler to do.  It is a question of a *fundamental tenet of C++ programming*:

> You shouldn't have to pay for what you don't need.

This philosophy prevails in every aspect of the design of the language, including how destructors are defined and work.

Every class needs a destructor of some kind.  That's why the compiler automatically writes one for you if you don't do it yourself.  This implicit destructor destroys all members and base classes in a specific order and in a specific way.  Sometimes this isn't what you really want, but that compiler can't assume this.  A classic case is with smart pointer classes.  A smart pointer class will have a raw pointer to the controlled object somewhere, but the compiler doesn't know if that pointer should be `delete`d -- maybe you are implementing a reference-counter smart pointer.  If you need the destructor to actually `delete` the pointer, that you have to write yourself.

Another case is with `delete`ing derived classes.  Consider:

```
Base* p = new Derived;
delete p;
```

If `Derived` has a bunch of stuff in it which needs to be released, then you need to make sure that when you `delete` the `Derived` object through the `Base` pointer, `Derived`'s destructor is the one that's actually called -- even though the compiler has no way of knowing at the call site that `p` actually points to a `Derived`.  In order to make this work, you need to make `Base::~Base` a `virtual` destructor.

Answer (score 4):

Neither C++ nor C++11 have garbage collection. C++11 does introduce a number of managed pointer classes in the **memory** header file--shared_ptr, weak_ptr and unique_ptr. These are designed to help prevent memory leaks. For an explanation see  [C++ Smart Pointers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541067/Cplusplus11-Smart-Pointers) tutorial and [Smart Pointers (Modern C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: As long as the most recent C++ standard is the 2011 one, C++ is C++11, isn't it?